# How an access an element within a valarray contained in a c array

Tags: c++, arrays, operator-overloading, valarray

I have a c array which contains valarrays as shown in the following code snipper,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <valarray>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

typedef uint uint32_t;
typedef std::valarray<uint32_t> uivector;

int main()
{
    uivector a[] = { uivector(uint32_t(1),8), uivector(uint32_t(2),4), uivector(uint32_t(3),5) };
}
```

Now how do I access, say, the third element of the second `valarray` (the value there is `2`), without making any copies and in a single line statement? Is it possible to overload the `[]` operator to achieve the same? something like `a[1][2]`?

Answer (score 1):

The the third element of the second valarray is indeed `a[1][2]`. The subscripting operator is already overloaded by `std::valarray`. No copies are made, the value of the expression `a[1][2]` is the actual object contained in the valarray.

Comment: No there is a problem with this. Try a index that goes out of bounds like a[1][20] and you will still see zero being printed out and it doesn't show index out of bounds error.

Comment: Is it possible to overload the second [] operator to do out of bounds check?

Comment: @Naveen: No. Just like with built-in array types, subscripting does not bounds check on `valarray` either. You cannot change that behaviour.